# How to add a "require" to the update command in Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to update a project according to the docs, but I get errors due to a "fixed package" in the `composer.lock` file. Then it tells me to list the `require` command as an argument for the `update` command:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"
```

> Problem 1
>
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^7.0, found laravel/framework [...] but the package is fixed to v6 by a partial
>   update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an
>   argument for the update command.

How can I then add it as requested?

Comment: Update from what to what and which steps are you taking. You should not need to install `laravel/ui` for an existing project so there must be something else wrong at a previous step

Comment: **Why** do you want to do that? Updating some other packages beyond their current requirements should be done in a seperate step. Something like updating Laravel is not done by simply adding a new line in composer.json

Comment: I am trying to update using this guide: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#authentication-scaffolding. Now I do use `laravel/ui` so I need to require it. But it then tells me that I need Laravel `7.x` for that. But it's locked to `6.x`. But when I first try to change the Laravel version in the `require` to `7.x` and do `update`, I get other errors relating to the `laravel/ui` not being in the correct version. It's like a loop. What I did now is to delete `composer.lock` and then move the `laravel/ui ^2.0` to the `require` block and run `update`. It worked.

Comment: But I know it might not be the best idea so I wonder how else I can fix that. Although, My Laravel installation was clean so no 3rd party packages and I kept all other versions as they were before except for the versions needed to be updated for the upgrade. But still I'm afraid it might have done some wrong stuff

Comment: But how do I actually need to do it? Do I need to set the new version value in `composer.json` and then run `update`? or `install`? or `update --with-all-dependencies`?

Comment: you cant install ui 2 until you manage to upgrade framework to v7

Comment: "It's a loop" - why? You could add the two new version numbers to your composer.json and run `composer update laravel/laravel laravel/ui`

Comment: set the required value in your composer.json file and run command : `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: @NicoHaase, first I should change their values in `composer.json`: (`"laravel/laravel: "^7.0"`) and then run the `composer update laravel/laravel laravel/ui` command?

Comment: Yeah, try that. If anything is not working with that, please add all details to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase another issue now: Since I am using an internal repo in the organization, the update doesn't work. From some reason, there are dozens (?!) of repos he tries to update from private packages on GitHub.. why? Why can't it update directly from packagist? I can't download from GitHub, only from packagist because I am using that secured internal repo that only installs via packagist

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - also, "doesn't work" is a pretty broad description of your problem. Clarify what that means if you need help

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to update your packages.
you can remove `composer.lock` and `vendor` folder, then you can change `laravel/ui` package version inside of `composer.json`, after that you need to run `composer update` to generate new `composer.lock` and vendor folder

Comment: Deleting the lock file is usually never a good idea, as this leads to new versions for a lot of packages while not all of them are needed to resolve the problem properly

Comment: yes your right, but he/she didnt explained problem totally and i suggested a public way. but as you know `composer.lock` file generates if we run `composer update` command again. and when we dont remove `composer.lock` command, sometimes we got error.
@NicoHaase thank you

Comment: "sometimes we got error" - then you should resolve it properly, and not by brute force